# Why do package versions get obsoleted and become unavailable?

Tags: 16.04, package-management

We are building docker images based on Ubuntu `xenial` (I know EOL 04/21) and we were using `curl=7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14` and `openssh-server=1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8` and both are now unavailable.

The curl package is now `curl=7.47.0-1ubuntu2.15` and the ssh-server `openssh-server=1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10`. I am wondering why this is and how the two original packages have just become unavailable?

Is there a way I can still get a hold of the old packages if need be? If so, where?

Comment: Generally speaking all packages remain available in launchpad.  So for example curl in 16.04 is here, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/curl  , Ex.  built files for amd64, (.debs), here, https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/17748854

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use the `rmadison` package database query and http://changelogs.ubuntu.com to find out why those packages were superseded.

Let's look at curl first:

```
$ rmadison curl | grep xenial
 curl | 7.47.0-1ubuntu2    | xenial           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 curl | 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.15 | xenial-security  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 curl | 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.15 | xenial-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
```

Aha: See how both -security and -updates are both pushing 2.15? That means it was likely a security patch. For specific details, let's take a look at  https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/binary/c/curl/7.47.0-1ubuntu2.15/changelog

> curl (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.15) xenial-security; urgency=medium
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: curl overwrite local file with -J
>
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2020-8177.patch: -i is not OK if -J is used in
>     src/tool_cb_hdr.c, src/tool_getparam.c.
>   - CVE-2020-8177
>
> -- Marc Deslauriers marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com  Wed, 17 Jun 2020 09:21:55 -0400

---

Now let's look at openssh-server:

```
$ rmadison openssh-server | grep xenial
 openssh-server | 1:7.2p2-4           | xenial           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 openssh-server | 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8  | xenial-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 openssh-server | 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10 | xenial-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
```

See how -updates has a higher version? That means the new package is likely a bugfix instead of a security patch. Let's see what https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/binary/o/openssh-server/1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10/changelog has to say:

> openssh (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10) xenial; urgency=medium
>
> - Fix deadlock when AuthorizedKeysCommand produces a large output.
>   (LP: #1877454)
>
>   - d/p/authkeyscommand-deadlock-01.patch: Make sure to call fclose(2)
>     and assign NULL to the file handler used to read
>     "Authorized{Keys,Principal}Command" directives.
>   - d/p/authkeyscommand-deadlock-02.patch: Consume entire output
>     generated by the command pointed by
>     "Authorized{Keys,Principal}Command" in order to avoid sending a
>     SIGPIPE to the process.
>
> -- Sergio Durigan Junior sergio.durigan@canonical.com  Wed, 13 May 2020 10:12:28 -0400

Answer (score -1):

Q: Is there a way I can still get a hold of the old packages if need be? If so, where?
A: Here is a useful source [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) however it is to be used at your own risk.

Comment: Hey why the down-vote? The poster asked a question within the question and I addresed that specifically.